# Describe a geometrical shape as a piecewise function

Tags: function, geometry, rotation

Consider a cube filled with random particles. Let's say the particles in cube are rotated around the z-axis through the center of the cube. Here, the rotation is proportional to the height of the cube, so no rotation at the bottom of the cube, and the rotation gradually increases with the height. In doing that we get the following shapes:
[image]

and that's how it looks like when we add particles inside the cube and rotate them:
[image]

Now when the rotated particles in 3D are projected onto a 2D plane, and then count the number of points in each pixel. We can then visualize this 2D histogram as a heatmap, which will give an image where the colour of each pixel corresponds to the number of particles projected onto that pixel after the rotation. The image formed looks like this:
[image]

How can I describe the geometry of the side AREAS (in pink) as a piecewise function where each piece represents the height of the pixels as a function of x,y and rotation $\theta$ for each region? It should have 12 pieces except for the middle region in yellow whose height has a maximum value "c", so it is mostly a flat surface.

What is the best way to describe the geometries of the side areas? to look something like this?

[image]

The goal is to multiply the equations of the sides by their inverse to elevate their values, so the region of the side becomes as high as the middle flat surface with the value "c"

Comment: Why wouldn't spline regression work? https://www.publichealth.columbia.edu/research/population-health-methods/spline-regression

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sort of straightedge-and-compass construction to help find the angle of rotation

- The construction part: For a given point draw a circle, find the point where it crosses the square.
- Finally: determine the angle with that point which gives you the amount of rotation and the height, or heights.

Graphic example: for a given point A, compute the distance to the origin. Then compute the point B on the edge of the non-transformed square with the same distance. Use A and B to compute the angle.

[image: example of construction]

With this approach you can work out the formulas. I skip that step because it is complicated and doesn't make this answer more clear (and maybe a little bit because it is annoying work).